# Complexity of this stack

Tags: stack, time-complexity, big-o

Isn't the complexity defined the given Stack solution = n^2??

[Codechef Editorial Link](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/27700/chfqueue-editorial)

Since, the outer loop is 1:N
and the pop-operation is also O(N-1) ~= O(N) (worst case scenario) ...
so isn't this N^2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Think of it this way: each chef gets pushed onto the stack *at most once*, and gets popped at most once too. Since you only go through the list once, the number of stack operations is bounded by 2N, i.e. time complexity = O(N).

Comment: Pseudo Code for the same:

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{

push(chef[i]);

while(top>top-1)
{
pop(top);
//in worst case loop runs n-1 times
}

}

so wouldn't this sum up to n^2??

Comment: @user23501 since the worst case is the number of elements on the stack, it decreases by the number of `pop` operations each loop, so if you have a really bad case early on you can only get small ones later. The number of `pop` operations will never exceed O(N)

Comment: Oh, got it, very helpful.

Comment: I tried last time too...but it showed:
"Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but not shown publicly"